Elastic search index creation - issue with nested property
I am trying to build a create index request using the Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch v8.13.7. My index should contain nested object collection, but when I do p.Nested and then pp.Properties it still shows the original type, ShopArticleDoc, and not the type of collection item, ArticleDoc. Is it possible to get nested properties in fluent way?
public class ShopArticleDoc
{
    // ...
    public List<ArticleDoc> Articles { get; set; } = new();
}

public class ArticleDoc
{
    //...
}

// ...

var response = await client.Indices.CreateAsync<ShopArticleDoc>(indexName, c =>
    c.Mappings(map =>
    {
        map.Properties(p =>
        {
            p.Nested(x => x.Articles, cc =>
            {
                cc.Properties<ArticleDoc>() // error here, can't provide generic type
                //cc.Properties(pp => // pp is a PropertiesDescriptor<ShopArticleDoc>
            });
        });
    })
);


As the generic method seemed unusable for me, I ended up using non-generic version
var response = await client.Indices.CreateAsync(new CreateIndexRequest(indexName)
{
    Mappings = new TypeMapping()
    {
        Properties = new Properties(new Dictionary<PropertyName, IProperty>()
        {
            { "id", new KeywordProperty() { IgnoreAbove = 256 } },
            { "type", new IntegerNumberProperty() },
            { "customerId", new KeywordProperty() { IgnoreAbove = 256 } },
            { "alias", new KeywordProperty() { Index = false } },
            {
              "articles",
              new NestedProperty()
              {
                  Properties = new Properties(new Dictionary<PropertyName, IProperty>()
                  {
                      { "id", new KeywordProperty() { IgnoreAbove = 256 } },
                      {
                        "sku", new TextProperty()
                        {
                            Fields = new Properties()
                            {
                                { "keyword", new KeywordProperty() { IgnoreAbove = 256 } }
                            }
                        }
                    },
               }
             }
         })
    }
});

